# Running multiple mocha files and suites with same context

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, mocha.js, integration-testing

I'm trying to run several integration tests with some shared context. The context being shared is a single express application, and I'm trying to share it across suites / files because it takes a few seconds to spin up.

I got it to work by instantiating a "runner" mocha test suite, that would have test functions that would just `require` each test file as needed, and this was working well (a side effect is that the test requiring the child test file would finish as "success" before any of the tests inside the file would actually run, but this was a minor issue)

```
// test-runner.js:

describe('Integration tests', function () {
  let app
  let log
  this.timeout(300000) // 5 mins
  before(function (done) {

    app = require('../app')
    app.initialize()
      .then(() => {
        done()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        log.error(err)
        done(err)
      })
  })

  it('Running api tests...', (done) => {
    require('./integration/api.test')(app)
    done()
  })
```

```
// ./integration/api.test.js:

module.exports = (app) => {
  let api = supertest.agent(app)
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  describe('Authorization', () => {
    describe('Trying to access authorization sections', () => {
      it('should be denied for /home', async () => {
        await api.get(`${baseUrl}/home`)
          .expect(STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED)
      })
...
```

**The Problem:**

I want to signal the test runner that all of the tests in the imported suite have finished, so I can call shutdown logic in the test runner and end the test cleanly. In standard test functions, you can pass a `done` function to signal that the code in the test is complete, so I wrapped each of the child tests in a describe block to use the `after` hook to signal that the whole test module was done:

```
// test-runner.js:

describe('Integration tests', function () {
  let app
  let log
  this.timeout(300000) // 5 mins
  before(function (done) {

    app = require('../app')
    app.initialize()
      .then(() => {
        done()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        log.error(err)
        done(err)
      })
  })

  it('Running api tests...', (done) => {
    require('./integration/api.test')(app, done)
  })
```

```
// ./integration/api.test.js:

module.exports = (app, done) => {
  let api = supertest.agent(app)
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  describe('All api tests', () => {
    let api
    before(() => {
      api = supertest.agent(app)
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    })
    after(() => {
      done()  // should be calling the done function passed in by test runner
    })
    describe('Authorization', () => {
      describe('Trying to access authorization sections', () => {
        it('should be denied for /home', async () => {
          await api.get(`${baseUrl}/home`)
            .expect(STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED)
        })
...
```

but when I do this, the test suites just don't run. The default timeout will just expire, and if I set a higher timeout, it just sits there (waiting for the longer timeout). If I hook into a debug session, then the test exits immediately, and the after hook (and before!) never get called.

I'm open to other ideas on how to do this as well, but I haven't found any good solutions that that allow sharing some context between tests, while having them broken into different files.